# integer expression expected bash

Tags: bash, scripting

Trying to loop a phrase inputted by the user a set amount of times that is also inputted by the user. Keep on getting the error integer expression expected, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

```
#!/bin/sh 
echo "What do you want to say?"
read phrase 

echo "How many times?"
read num

while [ "num" -ge 0 ]
do
     echo $phrase
     num='expr num - 1'
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a `$` to expand a variable in bash, unless it's inside of `(( ))`. You are comparing the literal string "num" to the number 0. Use one of the following:

```
while [ "$num" -ge 0 ] # POSIX
while (( num >= 0 )); # bash
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of corrections.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "What do you want to say?"
read phrase

echo "How many times?"
read num

while [ $num -gt 0 ];
do
     echo $phrase
     let num='num - 1'
done
```

#### Example

```
$ ./cmd.bash 
What do you want to say?
hi
How many times?
4
hi
hi
hi
hi
```

You can make the recalculation of `$num` a little more streamlined and easier to read with this notation.

Change this line:

```
     let num='num - 1'
```

with this:

```
     ( num-- ))
```

It gets confusing as to when to use or not use the `$` notation for variables, generally you'll want to consult the man page for `bash` and `test` when doing this kind of work. This change is apt if you're using `bash` and not just native `sh`.

#### Details

1. You need to use the variable form of `$num` when performing the bounds check in the `while` loops control section.
2. Use `let` instead of `expr`.
3. The bound for the loop is including the 0 step with `-ge` which will give you 1 more than what you want.

#### Example

With the `while` loops bound check using `-gt` you get this result:

```
$ ./cmd.bash 
What do you want to say?
hi
How many times?
2
hi
1
hi
0
```

If you use your `-ge` you'll get this behavior:

```
$ ./cmd.bash 
What do you want to say?
hi
How many times?
2
hi
1
hi
0
hi
-1
```

Comment: Even better than `let`: `(( num++ ))`

Comment: @jordanm - thanks I'll change it, I don't do much math in the shell anymore, usually use Perl for this type of stuff 8-)

Comment: I wouldn't change it, just the comment will do. The OP tagged the question bash but has `sh` in their shebang. The alternate method I presented won't work in POSIX sh.

Comment: @jordanm - I incorporated it into the answer, but left the original intact as well.